# How know if mediaplayer controls on notification are playing music or not?

Tags: android, audio, notifications, media-player

I'm doing a sound app that contains a main activity and 2 services, in the mainActivity I can control if the music is played or paused manually with a button on the main activity(so you can see it on the screen) that starts a service which active/stop mediaplayer. Moreover, I have a media player control on notification in other service for control the play/stop on the background. The problem is that I need to cordinate the notification in the background with the main controls of the main activity,  for example when I put the lockscreen (with the music is playing) and I press stop on the notification, the music doens't stop because in the main activity the service of mediaplayer continues enabled. So, I need to know when the notification is playing music or not in the main activity for doing a boolean (if the notification stops the music, i want that de mediaplayer service stops the music). 
Thank you all!
This is the code of my notification :

```
 public class Notificaciones extends Service {
public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "action_play";
public static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "action_pause";
public static final String ACTION_REWIND = "action_rewind";
public static final String ACTION_FAST_FORWARD = "action_fast_forward";
public static final String ACTION_NEXT = "action_next";
public static final String ACTION_PREVIOUS = "action_previous";
public static final String ACTION_STOP = "action_stop";
public static final String ACTION_BAR = "action_bar";

private MediaSession mSession;
private MediaSessionManager mManager;
private MediaController mController;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    if (mManager == null) {
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mSession = new MediaSession(getApplicationContext(), "example");
        mController = new MediaController(getApplicationContext(), mSession.getSessionToken());
        mSession.setCallback(new MediaSession.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onPlay() {
                super.onPlay();
                Log.e("MyServiceClass", "onPlay");
                buildNotification(generateAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Pause", ACTION_PAUSE));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                Log.e("MyServiceClass", "onPause");
                buildNotification(generateAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Play", ACTION_PLAY));

            }

            @Override
            public void onSkipToNext() {
                super.onSkipToNext();
                buildNotification(generateAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Pause", ACTION_PAUSE));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFastForward() {
                super.onFastForward();


            }

            @Override
            public void onRewind() {
                super.onRewind();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStop() {
                super.onStop();
                Log.e("MyServiceClass", "onStop");
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.cancel(1);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyServiceClass.class);
                stopService(intent);
            }
        });
    }



    handleIntent(intent);

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e("MyServiceClass", "onStop");
    mController.getTransportControls().stop();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(1);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyServiceClass.class);
    stopService(intent);
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    mMediaPlayer.release();
    stopSelf();


    super.onDestroy();
}

private void handleIntent (Intent intent){

    if (intent == null || intent.getAction()==null){
        return;
    }

    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PLAY)){

        mController.getTransportControls().play();


    }else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PAUSE)){

        mController.getTransportControls().pause();

    }else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_FAST_FORWARD)){

        mController.getTransportControls().fastForward();
    }else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_REWIND)){

        mController.getTransportControls().rewind();
    }else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PREVIOUS)){

        mController.getTransportControls().skipToPrevious();
    }else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_NEXT)){

        mController.getTransportControls().skipToNext();
    }else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_STOP)){

        mController.getTransportControls().stop();
    }if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_BAR)){

        mController.getTransportControls().stop();
    }



}
private android.app.Notification.Action generateAction(int icon, String title, String intentAction){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyServiceClass.class);
    intent.setAction(intentAction);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
    return new android.app.Notification.Action.Builder(icon, title, pendingIntent).build();
}

private void buildNotification(android.app.Notification.Action action){

    android.app.Notification.MediaStyle style = new android.app.Notification.MediaStyle();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyServiceClass.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_STOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
    android.app.Notification.Builder builder = new android.app.Notification.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo).setContentTitle("TEEN FM").setContentText("Adolescents.cat")
            .setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent).setStyle(style);

    builder.addAction(generateAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause,  "Previous", ACTION_PREVIOUS));
    builder.addAction(generateAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_rew,  "Rewind", ACTION_REWIND));

    builder.addAction(action);

    builder.addAction(generateAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_ff,  "Fast Forward", ACTION_FAST_FORWARD));
   builder.addAction(generateAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next", ACTION_NEXT));
    style.setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());


}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    mSession.release();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You should declarate your MediaPlayer like a static Object in your MainActivity and you will call it from the Notificaciones Service.

```
private static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
```

MainActivity main;

When you want stop it, you should do the next thing:

```
main=new MainActivity();
main.mMediaPlayer.stop
```

//this is an example, i don't know how is your player working. Because If your are creating anohe instance of you MediaPlayer you will not stop it never from the Service. The MediaPlayer service is an instance and the Activity MediaPlayer is another one.

If you need more help me. Let me know. Have a nice day!